# Sandcastle not documenting none library projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sandcastle

I'm new to Sandcastle. The version I am using is 2018.7.8.0. I have a solution in visual Studio 2015 that has 2 projects, one of them is a class library (has XMl and dll files in sandcastle) and the other is a usual C# console application has XMl and exe files in sandcastle).

When building the project in Sandcastle or Visual Studio, I get only the class library project documented in the index.html file.

Is there a way to include the other project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know - XML comments must be added to your code to document the various types and their members.

In addition, you must enable XML comments file output for the project.

1. In the Solution Explorer, right click on the project and select Properties.
2. Select the Build property page.
3. In the Output section, check the checkbox next to the Xml documentation file text box and specify a name for the XML file. Although not required, a common convention is to name the XML comments file after the related assembly (except with a .xml extension). The assembly name can be found on the Application property page.
4. If you have **a solution with multiple projects** that need to be documented, repeat the above steps for each project in the solution. It is recommended that you give each project's XML comments file a unique name.

For using Sandcastle you'll find a walkthrough [Creating Your First Project](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/d5dbf017-25f1-48cb-86db-90f76ee8f4d7.htm).